# Creating search functionality for profiles in my blog app based in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to extend my django blog app by creating a search form for User model based profiles.
Currently any profile page is only accessed by the current logged in User with simple base url corresponding to the following urlpattern.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/', views_register.profile, name='profile'),  
]
```

I am fetching user search query from the following html template.

```
<form method="GET" action="" id="searchform">
            <input class="searchfield" id="searchbox" name="q" type="text" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" placeholder="Search..."/>
        </form>
```

In my views.py, I have a function to receive this query but I don't know how to redirect the searching user to the corresponding user profile as the profile page for each user doesn't have any specific username based custom url.

```
class ProfileSearch(LoginRequiredMixin):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        query = request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            return User.objects.filter(username__icontains=query)
        else:
            return User.objects.all()
```

How do I redirect the query initiator to this new profile page? I know this function does nothing as it doesn't do any dynamic redirects but I am clueless.

Following is the profile model and is auto created through signals when a new user registers.

```
class Profile(models.Model):


user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default= 'default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Comment: I think you need to have an action on submit of the html form, for example an URL. If the search parameter is submitted, then the requester is redirected to the URL. This URL could possibly be a page with a ListView that shows the results of the search.